# binding nested structures to datagridview

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview

I have two Structures, one of them is nested.

```
Public Structure RetailRpt
    Public FromDate As Date
    Public ToDate As Date
    Public GenDate As Date
    Public RetailId As Integer
    Public TotalSellAmt As Integer
    Public CancelSellAmt As Integer
    Public NetSellAmt As Integer
    Public PayOut As Integer
    Public OperatorBal As Integer
    Public AgentDiscountAmt As Integer
    Public NetToPay As Integer
End Structure
Public Structure DSRpt
    Public FromDate As Date
    Public ToDate As Date
    Public GenDate As Date
    Public Retail() As RetailRpt <-- this one is nested
    Public NetSellAmt As Integer
    Public PayOut As Integer
    Public AgentDiscountAmt As Integer
    Public NetToPay As Integer
End Structure
```

I've added the DSRPT structure from the datasource of the datagridview. but unfortunately I can't manage to show the nested structure data with [+] in the datagridview row.
Please help me, I'm using VB.NET on Window form app.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Currently I'm using this code to add the main structure to the bindingsource   -----> Dim GetDSRpt() As localhost.DSRpt
Dim ret() As localhost.RetailRpt
GetDSRpt = ws.CreateDSRpt(FromDate, ToDate, 1)
ret = GetDSRpt(0).Retail
DSRptBindingSource.Clear()
DSRptBindingSource.Add(GetDSRpt(0))

Comment: Please edit that into your question with [formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: I'm trying to figure out a similar problem: Displaying a nested DataGridViews. What I have so far is handling the DataGridViewBindingComplete Event to populate the fields "manually" ala http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683796/winforms-datagridview-databind-to-complex-type-nested-property
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think is trully hard to get it done with a traditional GridView, I recomend you to use either an MSFlexGrid or if it's too ugly for you, try with a third party control, there's a thread about it here: [Good Quality Free Gridview for .NET WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563383/good-quality-free-gridview-for-net-winforms)