# Data Grid that allow edition by user in Windows Forms 2.0 using c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagrid, tabular

I am trying to create a data grid like a table that allow to the users insert data into cells in runtime in Windows Forms with .Net 2.0.

The main idea is a data grid like a table with editable cells for the final users and save that data

Answer (score 1):

Why isn't DataGridView good for this ?

It supports adding new rows, you can modify cell contents, there are even ways to implement much custom editing functionality...

Comment: Well I want to not just modify cell contents, I want to know wich of the cells change, set a row disable, tell a cell that is the sum of others cells and go on. Can I do that using DataGridView??

Comment: You can do most of those things. You can always know which cells changed, either by data binding to a datatable, I mean, this is the most basic functionality. Also, you can disable rows by setting them readonly, you can have calculated column;
I would say that you need to search and check these specific questions on the Internet.

Comment: It is true that most of those thing can be done, but it is messy, a lot of code for each minor layout modification, it is messy, sometimes is very messy. I would like to find some free third party control to do so, or any help from you to see if another winforms control is better.

Answer (score 0):

Telerik has really good user controls, including editable grids.  It isn't free, however.

http://www.telerik.com

Comment: any idea where I can find a free one??

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563383/good-quality-free-gridview-for-net-winforms